# Riemann Lebesgues lemma in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Is it still true that :

$$ \int_{\mathbb R } [f(x) \sin(nx)]^p dx \to 0 \text{ when } n \to \infty $$

I can't find anything about it.
Thanks.

Comment: what is your $f$?

Comment: Oh yeah. f was in riemann lebesgues lemma L1, but here maybe you would need Lp??

Comment: No. That integral has nothing to do with $\hat f$.

Comment: What do you mean? I m not talking about f hat

Comment: The intuition should be that is definitely false for p even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails for $p=2$. Indeed, 
$$
\sin^2(nx)=\frac{e^{2inx}-2+e^{-2inx}}{-4}=\frac 12-\frac 12\cos\left(2nx\right)
$$
hence for each function $f$ which is square integrable, in view of the classical Riemann Lebesgue lemma, 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R } [f(x) \sin(nx)]^2 dx \to 1/2
$$
and not $0$. The reasoning can be extended to the case where $p$ is an even integer.

Also, a version in $L^p$ with absolute values will fail for $p=1$ because 
$$
\left\lvert f(x)\sin(nx)\right\rvert\geqslant \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert
\sin^2(nx)=\left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert\left(\frac 12-\frac 12\cos\left(2nx\right)\right).$$